# How to use static int value in swift?

Tags: swift, function, static

Basically I am doing some computation for which I need to have an `Int` variable initiating with `0` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` everytime I reload the table view.

In Objective-C, I used this in cellForRowAtIndexPath of UITableView

```
static int rowSum= 0; 
rowSum += [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.Row] intValue];
```

How do we do this in Swift language ? The suggested link does not do that.

Comment: How did you do it in Objective-C? It doesn't sound like a `static` at all, from what you've said so far.

Comment: It compiles in objective-c but what purpose was served by calling it static?

Comment: I have a textfield in cell in which a number will be entered by the user. So Something like this I want to do - static int rowSum= 0; for(int i=0; i<=10;i++){ rowSum+= rowSum + TextFieldValue}

Comment: exact duplicate of [Static function variables in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354882/static-function-variables-in-swift)

Comment: Matt - please see the edit :-)