# How write getter method in swift same like objective C, with better ways

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here I have added code with getter method for one time allocation in obj c. How we will write same code in swift. I need one time allocation. I already seen the computed get and set method, but can't find a solution for this.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bgImageView;

- (UIImageView *)bgImageView{
    if (_bgImageView == nil) {
        _bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 277)];
        _bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
        _bgImageView.alpha = 0;
        _bgImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"f4f4f4"];
    }
    return _bgImageView;
}

[self.view addSubview:self.bgImageView];
```

Comment: then go with lazy properites. it will allocated only when u used it .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34204555/3400991 please go with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift introduced a new concept, **lazy** property. A lazy property is initialized only when you use it for the first time. Like a custom getter in objective-C, you can also add some logic after creating the object (for example, in your case, setting alpha value, image, and background color)

```
lazy var bgImageView:UIImageView  = {
    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 27))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
    imageView.alpha = 0
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 244/255, green:  244/255, blue:  244/255, alpha: 1)
    return imageView
}()
```

The code is called only once, but Apple warns about multithreading access :

> If a property marked with the lazy modifier is accessed by multiple
>   threads simultaneously and the property has not yet been initialized,
>   there is no guarantee that the property will be initialized only once.

Comment: ok , lazy var will allocate only once when first time call used. but are you sure it will allocate only once ?

Comment: Lazy properties are made for delay the initialization and the code will be called only once. I've edited my answer to add an exception from Swift Programming Guide: when multiple thread try to access a lazy property not initialized, it can be allocated multiple time.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/34204555/3400991 this link has perfect answer for ur question.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo I got this error for this code . Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type 'UIImageView'  Do we need to add `()` at the end of closure

Comment: Just edited my answer, you have to add '()' at the end of the code. My fault !