# Set frame of view once

Tags: swift

Some of the frames of my views can be set only after `layoutSubviews` has been called:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    let border = CAShapeLayer()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

        border.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layer.insertSublayer(border, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        border.frame = layer.bounds
        border.path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).CGPath
    }
}
```

Because I want to animate `border` in a later state, I only want the code in `layoutSubviews` to be called once. To do that, I use the following code:

```
var initial = true

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if initial {
        border.frame = layer.bounds
        border.path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).CGPath

        initial = false
    }
}
```

---

### **Question:**

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this. A more elegant and functional way, without having to use an extra variable.

Comment: Consider constraining your views programmatically.

Comment: Everything is already done in code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it without an extra variable (albeit not particularly elegant too) which relies on [lazy static properties initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203623/how-do-i-execute-code-once-and-only-once-in-swift):

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    struct InitBorder {
        // The static property definition
        static let run: Void = {
            border.frame = layer.bounds
            border.path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).CGPath
        }()
    }

    let border = CAShapeLayer()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

        border.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layer.insertSublayer(border, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // The call which initializes the static property
        let _ = InitBorder.run
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let initial = false

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if initial {
        border.frame = layer.bounds
        border.path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).CGPath

        initial = false
    }
}
```

Comment: By initializing `initial` to false, the code in the `if`-block never runs. Besides, it should be `var initial` if its value is to be changed.