# If if statement returns true never execute that function

Tags: swift

I've a function with if statement inside it, I want to check everytime person clicks, whenever the if statement returns true, I want that function to be removed or never again called, is it possible to achieve in swift?

```swift
    func checkLevelUp(){
        if CookieViewController.moneyLevel >= 3 && CookieViewController.bonusLevel >= 3 && CookieViewController.spinLevel >= 3 {
            print("Level up !!!!!!!") // if this is printed, I never want checkLevelUp function to exists
        }
    }
```

Comment: use a static variable in a function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354882/static-function-variables-in-swift  Then the function will remember the value of the variable.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah never, ever, should anyone recommend the usage of global variables to beginners. It creates the conditions for later subtle bugs that are not easy to find.

Comment: @Cristik a static local function variable isn't the same thing as a global variable.  The scope is limited to the function.  The posted answer (below) though...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah besides being not accessible from other places, a local static variable has the same downsides as the global ones. There are only a few valid reasons to have to resort to this kind of workaround, and the one in the question just doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store this particular state outside the scope of this function.

```
var didLevelUp = false

func checkLevelUp() {
    guard !didLevelUp else {
        return // return out of the function if `didLevelUp` is not false
    }
    if CookieViewController.moneyLevel >= 3 &&
        CookieViewController.bonusLevel >= 3 &&
        CookieViewController.spinLevel >= 3 {
        print("Level up !!!!!!!")
        didLevelUp = true
    }
}
```

How you store it outside the scope of the function is up to you but this is the solution you're looking for.